# Android Application to Install a font

Tags: android, fonts

I wanna create an application in android to install a Hindi Font. Can some one guide me how i can go about it ? is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot install a font on a device.

You can package a font as an asset with your application to be used by your application.

Comment: But there are many guides that say i can install one by some method

Comment: @Harsha M V: There are no guides that say you can install a font from an SDK application. If you make your own firmware, you can add whatever fonts you want. If you root you phone, you may be able to add fonts.

Comment: i meant something like this http://www.android-devs.com/?p=33 using an application

Comment: @Harsha M V: The third paragraph of that blog post contains: "These steps will require that you have root access". You cannot install a font from an SDK application.

Comment: yeah. was wondering if i can be done via Application by giving permissions.

Comment: @Harsha M V: No. **You cannot install a font from an SDK application.**

Answer (score 4):

Add the font file you want to use in the assets folder of your Android application. Then you can load the font and use it like this:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getContext().getAssets();
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager,"GILB.TTF");
TextView logo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.logo);
logo.setTypeface(tf);
```

In this case, I've used the true type font Gill Sans Bold.

Comment: i wanna install the font on to the device. Loooks like i cant do that.